# Show line number of warning in React component

Tags: html, reactjs, fbjs

[image]
Is there a way to view the line number of the js file containing the offending `<a>`?

This warning is produced by a package in [fbjs](https://github.com/facebook/fbjs) which comes with React.

Comment: I think after js file name :39 or :68 are line numbers

Comment: @Mohammad that's the library file from `fbjs`, not the component that's causing the problem.